# .htaccess not working in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a couple of sites that are currently under development and I've put them under a specific subfolder for clients/co-workers to view - "http://dev.staffanestberg.com/site-name/". I've run into some problems getting the sites working with .htaccess. I can reach the index page by typing in the url for a site folder but neither img/style/js/etc linking or page rewriting works. Looking for a solution to this, Apache's "RewriteBase" seems to be the most likely one, however I can't get it to work.
Tried
RewriteBase http://dev.staffanestberg.com/site-name/
RewriteBase /site-name
What would be the correct method?

Thanks in advance,
-Staffan

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show the full htaccess file?

Comment: Sure. The comment function won't allow me to fit the whole script but all redirects are the same:

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase http://dev.staffanestberg.com/site-name/

RewriteRule ^about-us about.php

Comment: Hm. No line breaks. How do I add one, by HTML chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mod_rewrite’s `RewriteBase` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) does only apply to rewrites using `RewriteRule`. And that does only apply for requests that are sent to the server.

But if the requested URIs are already wrong, `RewriteBase` doesn’t do any help. What you could try instead is the [HTML element `BASE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) that set’s the base URI for the current document.

Comment: Ah, I see. I did try the HTML base href tag but it didn't help. Perhaps I gave it an incorrect url? Tried http://dev.staffanestberg.com/site-name/. Note that the links are all given an "/" before their respective names (for example, "/logo.png").

Comment: @Staffan Estberg: Only the relative parts are resolved from that base URI; absolute parts are adopted as they stand. In your case the absolute URI path `/logo.png` is adopted as it stands and not resolved from `/site-name/` (in fact, resolving `/logo.png` from `/site-name/` yields `/logo.png`). To get `/site-name/logo.png` you will either need to use a relative path like `logo.png` or `./logo.png` or the absolute path `/site-name/logo.png`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the info. I replaced all occurances of "/x" with "./x". Problem solved!

Comment: @Staffan Estberg: Note that a base URI effects *all* relative URIs and not just relative URI paths.